# how to apply model developped in fast.ai / pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I've trained a model which i'm trying to apply onto new data. I'm totally new to fast.ai
i'm creating my databunch as below (ds being the data i want to score):

```
bs = 64
data_lm = (TextList.from_df(df, path, cols='comment_text')
            .split_by_rand_pct(0.1)
            .label_for_lm()
            .databunch(bs=bs))
```

The problem being that I cannot ommit the .split_by_rand_pct(0.1), so I cannot score the whole data

I then go and load/apply the model as below

```
data_clas = load_data(path, 'data_clas.pkl', bs=bs)
learn = text_classifier_learner(data_clas, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5)
learn.load_encoder('fine_tuned_enc')
learn.load('third');
preds, target = learn.get_preds(DatasetType.Test, ordered=True)
labels = preds.numpy()
```

But the problem is i'm only scoring 0.1 pct of my data as the first piece of code when I create the databunch is not correct...i'm wanting to apply the saved/loaded model onto the overall DF.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

a colleague of mine actually provided me with the solution, I'm posting it here in case it's useful to anyone.

```
learn.data.add_test(df['Contact_Text'])
preds,y = learn.get_preds(ds_type=DatasetType.Test)
preds
```